# Using IntelliJ IDEA, cannot figure out how to compile and run a simple program

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation

The code:

```
public class var3
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int num = 113;
        double num2 = 2.71828;
        string cs = "Computer Science";
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(num2);
        System.out.println(cs);
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out how to run it. When I click run, I see this:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Programming\unit1\out\production\unit1;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

But none of my System.out.println();'s.

Answer (score 0):

It's launching another class named `Main`, which I guess prints nothing:

```
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain **Main**
```

You can also see it in the combobox next to the green arrow. If you want to run another class (here `var3`), right click in your file and choose `Run 'var3.main()'`.

The green arrow always launches the run configuration selected in the combobox, not the file you are currently editing.